# Problem with Ubuntu password setting with numpad off

Tags: 14.04, login

I've Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Today I've changed My password and it contains numbers, When I set the password the num lock of numpad keys was off. Now I cannot login. I tried pressing the same keys with num lock  on or off. Any help????

Comment: As certain as death and taxes is Ubuntu about passwords. If it says it's wrong, it really is. If your password contains symbols then it could be a keyboard layout mismatch. The numpad is just noise, i.e., irrelevant and unrelated information. Unrelated because you can activate it *and* you can use the other numbers or is your keyboard so different as to not have number except in the numpad? This is assuming you are typing the correct password, it contains symbols and the keyboard layout is incorrect. A possible yet rare set of circumstances. A **human error** is far more likely.

Comment: For example on terminal if I press numpad key 3(num lock is off), It appends ~ .  is this a noise?

Comment: It seems you had the wrong keyboard layout when you set the password. Although you can try to figure out what layout it was, it's easier to reset the password (unless you encrypt your home directory and use that password to access the files--then you shouldn't reset it). Assuming you are still looking for a solution, [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) should let you put in a new password. After you regain convenient access to your system, you can proceed to check and change the keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using getty terminal(Ctrl + Alt+ F1). I provided the password the same way I set it( using numpad with num lock). I don't know how it worked but it did.